# '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I'm sorry. This error is driving me crazy. I just updated from Django's 1.11 to 2.0 and I'm unable to trace this simple casting error.

The traceback does not mention any part of my code...

I know what the error means. I'm just unable to find where is the issue in my code.

This error occurs when creating or editing the entry. Thru shell I can create the object just fine.

Traceback:

```
File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  574.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1556.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1450.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _changeform_view
  1498.                     return self.response_change(request, new_object)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_change
  1239.             self.message_user(request, msg, messages.SUCCESS)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in message_user
  1013.         messages.add_message(request, level, message, extra_tags=extra_tags, fail_silently=fail_silently)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/api.py" in add_message
  34.         return messages.add(level, message, extra_tags)

File "/home/rodrigo/Workspace/VirtualEnvs/firetail/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/base.py" in add
  140.         if level < self.level:

Exception Type: TypeError at /controle/enterprise/branch/7/change/
Exception Value: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

This is the settings/common.py file:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)


# Default
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {}

# Default
ADMINS = ()

# Default
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
        ]

# Default
APPEND_SLASH = True

# Default
CACHES = {
        'default': {
            #'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
            }
        }

# Default
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'firetail',
            'USER': 'firetail',
            'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            },
       'default_': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'database.db'),
            },
        'backup': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'database-backup.db'),
            }
        }

# Default
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []

# Default
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'

# Default
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
        '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
        '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
        '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
        '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
        '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
        )

# Default
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'

# Default
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
        '%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
        '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
        '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
        '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
        '%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
        '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
        '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
        '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
        '%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
        )

# Default
DEBUG = False

# Default
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = False

DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'

# Default
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'

# Default
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/html'

# Default
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'

# Default
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'

# Default
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL =  'webmaster@localhost'

# Default
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE = ''

# Default
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = ''

# Default
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = ()

# Default
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

# Default
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = 'localhost'

# Default
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'

# Default
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''

# Default
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''

# Default
EMAIL_PORT = 25

# Default
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django]'

# Default
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False

# Default
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False

# Default
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8'

# Default
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = (
        "django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler",
        "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler",
        )

# Default
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440

# Default
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = None

# Default
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = None

# Default
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None

# Default
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0 

# Default
FIXTURE_DIRS = ()

# Default
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = None

# Default
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = None

# Default
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = ()

# Default
INTERNAL_IPS = ()

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'rest_framework',
    'applications.frontend',
    'applications.backend',
    'applications.inventory',
    'applications.retail',
    'applications.workforce',
    'applications.enterprise',
    'applications.costumer',
    'applications.delivery',
    'bootstrap3',
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'

# Default
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE = None

# Default
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None

# Default
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'

# Default
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH = '/'

# LANGUAGES 

# Default
LOCALE_PATHS = ()

# LOGGING

# LOGGING_CONFIG


MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Default
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# Default
MEDIA_URL = ''

MIDDLEWARE = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        )

# Default
MIGRATION_MODULES = {}

# Default
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'

NUMBER_GROUPING = 3

# Default
PREPEND_WWW = False

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

# Default
SECRET_KEY = ''

# Default
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None

#SERIALIZATION_MODULES

# Default
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@localhost'

# Default
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'

# Default
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'

# Default
SIGNING_BACKEND = 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'

# Default
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = []

TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [
                    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'templates'),
                ],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'debug': DEBUG,
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                    'django.template.context_processors.media',
                    'django.template.context_processors.static',
                    'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'applications.enterprise.context.open_operation',
                    'applications.enterprise.context.enterprise',
                    ],
                },
            },
        ]




# Default
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'

# Default
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS = []

THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = '.'

USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False

# Default
TIME_FORMAT = 'P'

# Default
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
        '%H:%M:%S',     # '14:30:59'
        '%H:%M:%S.%f',  # '14:30:59.000200'
        '%H:%M',        # '14:30'
        )


TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

# Default
USE_ETAGS = False

# Default
USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

# Default
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False

#WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mytestsite.wsgi.application'

# Default
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'

# Default
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'



# --------- Auth Settings -------------------

# Default
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)

# Default
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/painel'

LOGIN_URL = '/entrar'

LOGOUT_URL = '/sair'

# Default
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = 3

# Default
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher')



# ------------ Comments Settings ----------


# Default
COMMENTS_HIDE_REMOVE = True

# Default
COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH = 3000

#COMMENTS_APP

# Default
PROFANITIES_LIST = ()


# --------------- Message Settings ----------------

# Default
MESSAGE_LEVEL = 'messages.INFO'

# Default
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'

# Default
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
        'messages.DEBUG': 'debug',
        'messages.INFO': 'info',
        'messages.SUCCESS': 'success',
        'messages.WARNING': 'warning',
        'messages.ERROR': 'error'
        }

# --------------- Sessions Settings ----------------

# Default
#SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS

# Default
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600

# Default
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None

# Default
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

# Default
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'

# Default
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'

# Default
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

# Default
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'


SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

# Default
SESSION_FILE_PATH = None

# Default
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False

# Default
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'


# --------------- Sites Settings ----------------


SITE_ID = 1



# --------------- Static Files Settings ----------------


STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, os.path.pardir,os.path.pardir,'static')]

#STATICFILES_STORAGE

#STATICFILES_FINDERS

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
#        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

This is my settings/devel.py

```
from settings.common import *

INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + (
        'django_extensions',
        ) 

DEBUG = True

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = None

SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXX'
```

Comment: Guys, I understand the issue. I understand that somewhere in my code there is a wrong type comparison. The issue here is that the Traceback in not helping me to find it.... The issue is arising only when creating or editing this specific entry in the Admin interface.... I'm just greping away my files looking for "<" but still not finding it... :(

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Django code. Are you literally using Django 2.0 or the latest maintenance release (`2.0.13`)?

Comment: I've tried other versions of Django. I'm still in 2.0 because I'm testing and checking my code. I'll upgrade further once everything works. Which it doesn't right now. :(

Comment: Just checked git blame and that part of `base.py` hasn't been updated for years. Really interesting. Are you using any middleware that could be messing with message storage of the request object?

Comment: The relevant bit of code in Django hasn't changed for years... it shouldn't even be possible to get the exception you got :S. Are you using a custom [storage backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#configuring-the-message-engine) for the messages framework? That seems to me to be the most likely source of an issue.

Comment: @Rodrogo Can you post your whole settings.py (scrutinized to remove secrets and passwords, obviously)?

Comment: Commenting out the "MESSAGE_LEVEL = 'messages.INFO'" line worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in `common.py`:

```
MESSAGE_LEVEL = 'messages.INFO'
```

You should change this to

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as message_constants
MESSAGE_LEVEL = message_constants.INFO
```

as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MESSAGE_LEVEL). I am surprised how it used to work before the migration.